# How to synchronise cron jobs execute at the same time with sidekiq-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In my project there are more than 250 cron jobs setup through sidekiq-scheduler (https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) gem, and all are execute every 2 hours, but I want to execute all in synchronise manner or say one job after another. Following is my sidekiq.yml file setup,

```
:schedule:   
  cron1:
    cron: '0 */2 * * *'
    class: Jobs::StartNew
    queue: low
    args: 
    description: 'This job executes the cron1'   
  cron2:
    cron: '0 */2 * * *'
    class: Jobs::StartNew
    queue: low
    args: 
    description: 'This job executes the cron2'   
  cron3:
    cron: '0 */2 * * *'
    class: Jobs::StartNew
    queue: low
    args: 
    description: 'This job executes the cron3'   
  cron4:
    cron: '0 */2 * * *'
    class: Jobs::StartNew
    queue: low
    args: 
    description: 'This job executes the cron4'   
 cron5:
    cron: '0 */2 * * *'
    class: Jobs::StartNew
    queue: low
    args: 
    description: 'This job executes the cron5
    :
    :
    :
 cron250:  
    cron: '0 */2 * * *'
    class: Jobs::StartNew
    queue: low
    args: 
    description: 'This job executes the cron250
```

There are `:resolution` option which I found from https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sidekiq-scheduler/0.4.1 but not confident it is for waiting time after each cronjob execution.

Can anyone help me to manage cron jobs execute one after another but at the same time. and so it does not loads on server memory.

Comment: How about configuring each cron to 1 minute distance? That way you will be able to predict the sequence as well.

Comment: If you want them to run after each other just schedule the next one to run at the end of its previous job. You shouldn't try to guess when one will end to start the other. Schedule 1 job and queue the next job at the end of that job.

Comment: @ricks yes but i want the way how to do it, I have 250 cron jobs which pushes the job. So basically I have to do something for cronjob.